# How to Remove Duplicate Profile URL Using Regular Expression?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, filtering

I have been trying to Fix the Regular Expression. But I could Not figure it Out. https://regexr.com/45h27. I always Get duplicate URL. Need to remove the Duplicate URL. It would be helpful If I get Explanation from your side. Thanks.

This is the expression That I tried

```
((http|https):\/\/|)(www\.|)facebook\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9.]{1,}
```

I need to filter the Duplicate URLS.

Comment: To make this a good question, add sample inputs and expected and actual results.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to remove duplicates in your code rather than in the regular expression.

Comment: @Henk-Holterman You may Check Here https://regexr.com/45h27 & I also added the link in my question.

Comment: Yes, but SO questions should stand by themselves. [edit] and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/[\w.]*)(?=[^w.])(?!.*\1)
```

It's your regex (somewhat simplified) with a negative look ahead added to make sure the URL isn't repeated later in the text. This means that **only the last match** is kept in the list.

```
((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/[\w.]*)
```

[See it here,](https://regexr.com/45h54)

[This will explain it for you graphically.](https://regexper.com/#%28%28%3F%3Ahttps%3F%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%29%3F%28%3F%3Awww%5C.%29%3Ffacebook%5C.com%5C%2F%5B%5Cw.%5D*%29%28%3F%3D%5B%5Ew.%5D%29%28%3F!.*%5C1%29).

Explanation lite:

`(:?`... `)` makes a non captured group.  `?` makes the character or group preceding it optional. `(?=[^w.])` - a positive look ahead is to make sure the whole URL is matched (followed by something NOT a word character or a dot). `(?!.*\1)` is a negative look ahead making sure capture group (the URL part captured between the `()`), preceded by anything (`.*`), doesn't repeat.

Comment: This is Great answer and Explanation. Thanks.